# jQuery.Mobile Date Picker - disable past dates

Tags: jquery, mobile, datapicker

I use jquery.mobile.datapicker.js, after you select a date in the first input, in the second I have to disable the past dates than written in the first input. Every solution proposed previously not able with jquery.mobile.datapicker.
I admit to being inexperienced in jquery , can you help ?

```
data partenza <input name="data_partenza" id="data_partenza" value="<%=date()%>" data-role="date" type="text" style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;">
```

second input

```
data partenza <input name="data_partenza" id="data_partenza" value="<%=date()%>" data-role="date" type="text" style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;">

data ritorno <input name="data_ritorno" id="data_ritorno" value="<%=date()%>" data-role="date" type="text" style="position: relative; z-index: 100000;">
```